# Непонятные звуковые сигналы BIOS

Tags: bios

На ноутбуке Sony Vaio в последнее время периодически появляются странные короткие звуковые сигналы от BIOS (сама BIOS AMI). Количество сигналов различается (бывают по 20-30 сигналов, а бывает по 6-8, точно сложно подсчитать - звуки идут быстро, но количество явно разное).

Провел диагностику - явных проблем нет, температура на датчиках тоже в порядке. Все остальное тоже работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема? Есть какие-нибудь специализированные программы для диагностики под этот случай?

P.S. Есть подозрения, что это может быть клавиатура или видеокарта. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: А клавиатура в порядке? А кулер?

Comment: Известные сигналы AMI BIOS: http://www.probios.ru/article/bios-error/ami-bios-beep-codes.html

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов клавиатура работает без проблем, кулер тоже. температура процессора в среднем 50-60, может подняться до 61-63, но не более.

Comment: @zed если с короткими группами звуков еще можно разобраться, то что означает писк, когда по 20-30 сигналов (явно больше 11). звуки проявляются в процессе работы, на старте запускается нормально. каких-либо зависимостей появления звуков и нагрузки (CPU, HDD, RAM) не выявлено.